# How can i block ttf to web use only(not using fontSquirrl)

Tags: font-face, truetype

I have a font(.ttf) that i want to make sure that no one will be able to download it and install it in his/her computer. i know there is an option to upload the font to fontSquirll and check under the advance mode the following Protection:  **WebOnly™** .

but since they share the fonts that were being converted to fontface i do not wish to use it.

Is there any program that can do that same locally?

Answer (score 0):

A [WOFF font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format) does exactly that: protect your font from being installed locally. Apart from some older Android browsers, WOFF support is virtually the same as TTF, and there are plenty of [easy tools](http://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff) out there to convert your TTF to WOFF.

Comment: I know that woff does that, but i still need the ttf as second Parachute.